# Python 3.x: Convert the dictionary values into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I hope you are having a great day. I want to convert these dictionary values into a list. Can anyone give me the idea? Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample data:

```
listb=[{'id': '1b33b33f-8e92-4068-a459-0a1de0febb7c'}, {'id': 'c56502b9-0632-4f9f-88b9-70f40e61ef5d'}]
```

And the output would be like this:

```
['1b33b33f-8e92-4068-a459-0a1de0febb7c', 'c56502b9-0632-4f9f-88b9-70f40e61ef5d']
```

Comment: `print([i['id'] for i in listb])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list-comprehension to solve this (assuming that the key is always `id`):

```
[el["id"] for el in listb]
```